# Why Symfony3 so slow?

Tags: symfony

I installed Symfony3 framework-standard-edition. I'm trying to open the home page(app.php prod) and it is loaded 300-400ms.
This is my profiler information:
[image]
 also I use php7.

Why it is so long?

Comment: And how you get dev toolbar in production?

Comment: You're right, this panel is not from production, but this is the only way to show what's going on under the hood of my project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to optimize Zend OPCache.
Here are some recommended settings

`opcache.revalidate_freq`
Basically put, how often (in seconds) should the code cache expire and check if your code has changed. 0 means it checks your PHP code every single request (which adds lots of stat syscalls). Set it to 0 in your development environment. Production doesn't matter because of the next setting.

`opcache.validate_timestamps`
When this is enabled, PHP will check the file timestamp per your `opcache.revalidate_freq` value.
When it's disabled, `opcache.revaliate_freq` is ignored and PHP files are NEVER checked for updated code. So, if you modify your code, the changes won't actually run until you restart or reload PHP (you force a reload with `kill -SIGUSR2`).
Yes, this is a pain in the ass, but you should use it. Why? While you're updating or deploying code, new code files can get mixed with old ones— the results are unknown. It's unsafe as hell

`opcache.max_accelerated_files`
Controls how many PHP files, at most, can be held in memory at once. It's important that your project has LESS FILES than whatever you set this at. For a codebase at ~6000 files, I use the prime number 8000 for maxacceleratedfiles.
You can run `find . -type f -print | grep php | wc -l` to quickly calculate the number of files in your codebase.

`opcache.memory_consumption`
The default is 64MB. You can use the function opcachegetstatus() to tell how much memory opcache is consuming and if you need to increase the amount.

`opcache.interned_strings_buffer`
A pretty neat setting with like 0 documentation. PHP uses a technique called string interning to improve performance— so, for example, if you have the string "foobar" 1000 times in your code, internally PHP will store 1 immutable variable for this string and just use a pointer to it for the other 999 times you use it. Cool.
This setting takes it to the next level— instead of having a pool of these immutable string for each SINGLE php-fpm process, this setting shares it across ALL of your php-fpm processes. It saves memory and improves performance, especially in big applications.
The value is set in megabytes, so set it to "16" for 16MB. The default is low, 4MB.

`opcache.fast_shutdown`
Another interesting setting with no useful documentation. "Allows for faster shutdown".
Oh okay. Like that helps me. What this actually does is provide a faster mechanism for calling the destructors in your code at the end of a single request to speed up the response and recycle php workers so they're ready for the next incoming request faster.
Set it to 1 and turn it on.

```
opcache=1
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=16
opcache.max_accelerated_files=8000
opcache.validate_timestamps=0
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

I hope it will help improve your performances

**[EDIT]**

You might also want to look at this answer:
[Are Doctrine relations affecting application performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712661/are-doctrine-relations-affecting-application-performance/58715183#58715183)

Comment: great response, thanks! Would someone know - when we're considering the number of files, let's say in case of Symfony, would it be enough to check the number of **cached** files only? Or we should take the whole app's Symfony installation into account (which would be ~4x more)?

Answer (score 3):

TheMrbikus, try some optimization with the following elements:

- Use APC
- Use Bootstrap files

Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/performance.html

Comment: There is no APC for PHP7

Answer (score 0):

- Use the OPCache PHP7
- Use Apache PHP-FPM.

E-mail sending process, and may slow down during the form rendering operations. Create a blank test Controller.