# Doctrine / MySQL Slow query even when using indexes

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I cleaned the question a little bit because it was getting very big and unreadable.

Running on my localhost.

As you can see in the image below, the query takes `755.15 ms` when selecting from the table Job that contains 15000 rows (with the where conditions returning 6650)

The table Company contains 1000 rows.
The table geo__name contains 84300 rows approx and is not giving me any problem, so I believe the problem is the database structure or something.

The structure of these 2 tables is the following:

Table Job is:

```
CREATE TABLE `job` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `activity_sector_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` datetime NOT NULL,
  `contract_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `salary_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `workday_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `geoname_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `minimum_experience` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_salary` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_salary` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vacancies` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `show_salary` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`,`active`,`status`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_FBD8E0F823F5422B` FOREIGN KEY (`geoname_id`) REFERENCES `geo__name` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_FBD8E0F8398DEFD0` FOREIGN KEY (`activity_sector_id`) REFERENCES `activity_sector` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_FBD8E0F85248165F` FOREIGN KEY (`salary_type_id`) REFERENCES `job_salary_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_FBD8E0F8979B1AD6` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_FBD8E0F8AB01D695` FOREIGN KEY (`workday_id`) REFERENCES `workday` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_FBD8E0F8CD1DF15B` FOREIGN KEY (`contract_type_id`) REFERENCES `job_contract_type` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The table company is:

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cifnif` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscription_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_4FBF094FA76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_4FBF094F9A1887DC` (`subscription_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`(191)),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_4FBF094F9A1887DC` FOREIGN KEY (`subscription_id`) REFERENCES `subscription` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_4FBF094FA76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The query is the following:

```
SELECT 
  j0_.id AS id_0, 
  j0_.status AS status_1, 
  j0_.title AS title_2, 
  j0_.min_salary AS min_salary_3, 
  j0_.max_salary AS max_salary_4, 
  c1_.id AS id_5, 
  c1_.name AS name_6, 
  c1_.logo AS logo_7, 
  a2_.id AS id_8, 
  a2_.name AS name_9, 
  g3_.id AS id_10, 
  g3_.name AS name_11, 
  j4_.id AS id_12, 
  j4_.name AS name_13, 
  j5_.id AS id_14, 
  j5_.name AS name_15, 
  w6_.id AS id_16, 
  w6_.name AS name_17 
FROM 
  job j0_ 
  INNER JOIN company c1_ ON j0_.company_id = c1_.id 
  INNER JOIN activity_sector a2_ ON j0_.activity_sector_id = a2_.id 
  INNER JOIN geo__name g3_ ON j0_.geoname_id = g3_.id 
  INNER JOIN job_salary_type j4_ ON j0_.salary_type_id = j4_.id 
  INNER JOIN job_contract_type j5_ ON j0_.contract_type_id = j5_.id 
  INNER JOIN workday w6_ ON j0_.workday_id = w6_.id 
WHERE 
  j0_.active >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
  AND j0_.status = 1 
ORDER BY 
  j0_.created_at DESC
```

When executing the above query I have these results:

In MYSQL Workbench: `0.578 sec / 0.016 sec`
In Symfony profiler: `755.15 ms`

The question is: Is the duration of this query correct? if not, how can I improve the speed of the query? it seems too much.

[image]

The Symfony debug toolbar if it helps:

[image]

As you can see in the below image, I'm only getting the data I really need:

[image]

The explain query:

[image]

The timeline:

[image]

Comment: To solve your problem, more information is needed. Provide information about the structure of the tables involved in the query and indexes.

Comment: @slico add please job_salary_type table structure

Comment: Are there 3 rows in j3_ and about 166 in j0_?  Does the `EXPLAIN` change between including the j7_ columns and not?

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_642A8732BE04EA9` (`job_id`),` -- Why have `id`; `job_id` could be the PK.  And... Since this is 1:1 with `job`, why have a separate table?

Comment: @RickJames I updated the question at the top of the question, i hope it helps, i think i managed to make it work correctly dividing the tables, now i have the "Description" field on the "job_content" table and the other fields inside "Job" table.

Comment: In the debug bar, what is the query count shown?

Comment: @Preciel Between 1000 and 2000 ms

Comment: the number of queries, not the duration... ;)

Comment: Now i have 9 queries because i have some dropdowns with query_builder. But the query that has the joins only executing 1 (the one in the question)

Comment: When you check the Symfony profiler, in doctrine tab, is there some duplicate query within the 9?

Comment: No, they are not duplicated queries

Comment: So your problem isn't from doctrine. Still, just in case, I guess you could read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712661/are-doctrine-relations-affecting-application-performance/58715183#58715183) I gave some time ago. Do you do a lot of loop (for ... in ...) in your twig view? Also, does your data contain blob chains?

Comment: No loops, only printing in twig, you can check the doctrine query in the original question i wrote:)

Comment: A full screenshot of the doctrine tab in the profiler would provide more data... haha.. Anyway, I will add an answer that might help you improve performances. Give me a moment... Not sure that your problem will be solved though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would start your performance by adding MySQL keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" which tells MySQL to query the data in the order I have provided, dont try to think the relationships for me.  However, on your dataset being so small, and already 1/2 second, don't know if that will help as much, but on larger datasets I have known it to SIGNIFICANTLY improve performance.

Next, you appear to be getting lookup descriptions based on the PK/FK relationship results.  Not seeing the indexes on those tables, I would suggest doing covering indexes which contain both the key and description so the join can get the data from the index pages it uses for the JOIN instead of use index page, find the actual data pages to get the description and continue.

Last, your job table with the index on (`created_at`,`active`,`status`), might perform better if the index had the index as ( `status`, `active`, `created_at` ).

With your existing index, think of it this way, each day of data is put into a single box.  Within each day box that is sorted by an active timestamp (even if simplified by active date), THEN the status.
So, for each day CREATED, you open a box.  Look at secondary boxes, one for each "Active" timestamp (ex: by day).  Within each Active timestamp (day), only now can you see if the "Status = 1" records.  So open each active timestamp day, assess Status = 1, then close each created day box and go to the next created day box and repeat.  So look at the labor intensive of open each box per day, each active box within that day.

Now, under the suggested index starting with status.  You now have a very finite number of boxes, one for each status.  Open only the 1 box for status = 1 These are the only ones you want to consider... All the others you don't care.  Inside that, you have the actual records based on ACTIVE Timestamp and that is sub-sorted.  From that, you can jump directly to those at the current timestamp.  From the first record and the rest within the box, you now have all the records that qualify.  Done.  Since these records (index) ALSO has the Created_at as part of the index, it can optimize that with the descending sort order.

For ensuring "covering indexes" for the other lookup tables if they do not yet exist, I suggest the following.

```
table              index
company            ( id, name, logo )
activity_sector    (id, name )
geo__name          ( id, name )
job_salary_type    ( id, name )
job_contract_type  ( id, name )
workday            ( id, name )
```

And the MySQL Keyword...

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN   (rest of query...)
```

Comment: If `id` is PK then `(id, name)` is kind of redundant with the clustered index. Note that a clustered index is always covering.

Comment: Adding this keys looks like good, something has improved, also i'm checking the computer and MySQL/xampp installation because i think it looks like corrupted, i'll come back and let you know, btw this solution looks great and as i say, it has improved a little bit

Comment: I uninstalled xampp and reinstalled again and now looks good, query loads at 100ms. The key status, active and created_at looks like also improved my loading speed.

Comment: @Slico, glad it worked, but curious on the bounty if you or just the system.  You checked my answer as resolution, yet another gets the bounty... I guess S/O does it based on most up-check marks.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL server can't handle the load being placed on it. This could be due to resource contention, or because it has not been appropriately tuned and it could also be a problem with your hard drive.

Comment: Checking this right now, looks like corrupted or something wrong with MySQL installation, i'll come back and let you now

Comment: Okey, so i uninstalled xampp and reinstalled again and the query now loads at 100ms what i think is a normal speed. Don't know why happened this, just thinking it was a query problem and was something involving my xampp installation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons as to why Symfony is slow.

<kbd>**1. Server fault**</kbd>

First, it could be the server fault. Server performances may hinder your query time.

<kbd>**2. Data size and defered rendering**</kbd>

Then comes the data size. As you can see on the image below, the query on one of my project have a 50Mb data size (currently about 20k rows).
Parsing 50Mb in HTML can take some time, mostly because of loops.
Still, there are solutions about this, like defered rendering.

[image]

Defered rendering is quite simple, instead of parsing data in your twig you,
send all data to a javascript varaible, and use javascript to parse/render data once the DOM is loaded.

<kbd>**3. Query optimisation**</kbd>

As I wrote in comment, you can check the following question, on which I explained why custom queries are important.
[Are Doctrine relations affecting application performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712661/are-doctrine-relations-affecting-application-performance/58715183#58715183)

In this question, you will read that order matter... It's in fact the most important thing.

While static data in your databases are often inserted in the right order,
it's rarely the case for dynamic data (data provided by user during the website life)

Which is why, using `ORDER BY` in your query will often speed up the page rendering,
as doctrine won't be doing extra queries on it's own.

As exemple, One of my site have about 700 entries diplayed on the index.
First, here is the query count while using `findAll()` :

[image]

It show 254 query (253 duplicates) in 144ms, plus 39 render time.
Next, using the second parameter of `findBy()`, `ORDER BY`, I get this result :

[image]

You can see the [full query here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe4hW.png) (sreenshot is big)
Much better, 1 query only in 8ms, and about the same render time.
But, here, I don't use any fields from associations.
From the moment I will do it, doctrine qui do some extra query, and query count and time will skyrocket.
In the end, it will turn back to something like `findAll()`

And last, this is the custom query :

[image]

In this [custom query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoMvd.png), the query time went from 8ms to 38ms.
But, unlike the previous query, I got way more data in my result,
which will prevent doctrine from doing extra query.
Again, `ORDER BY()` matter in this query. Without it, I skyrocket back to 84 queries.

<kbd>**4. Partials**</kbd>

When you do custom query, you can load partials objects instead of full data.
As you said in your question, `description` field seems to slow down your loading speed,
with partials, you can avoid to load some fields from the table, which will speed up query speed.

First, instead of your regular syntax, this is how you will create the query builder :

```
$em=$this->getEntityManager();
$qb=$em->createQueryBuilder();
```

Just in case, I prefer to keep `$em` as a separate variable (if I want to fetch some class repository for example).

Then you can start your partial `select`. Careful, first `select` can't include any association fields :

```
$qb->select("partial job.{id, status, title, minimum_experience, min_salary, max_salary, zip_code, vacancies")
   ->from(Job::class, "job");
```

Then you can add your associations :

```
$qb->addSelect("company")
   ->join("job.company", "company");
```

Or even add partial association in case you don't need all the data of the association :

```
$qb->addSelect("partial activitySector.{id}")
   ->join("job.activitySector", "activitySector");

$qb->addSelect("partial job.{id, company_id, activity_sector_id, status, active, contract_type_id, salary_type_id, workday_id, geoname_id, title, minimum_experience, min_salary, max_salary, zip_code, vacancies, show_salary");
```

<kbd>**5. Caches**</kbd>

You could also use various caches, like Zend OPCache for PHP, which you will find some advices in this question: [Why Symfony3 so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926751/why-symfony3-so-slow)

There is also the SQL cache Varnish.

---

This round up about everything I can share to lower your loading time.

Hope it will prove useful and you will be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

So many keys , try to minimize the number of keys.

Comment: I'm testing this right now, i'll come back to you and let you know. What i've done is move the description field to another table and now the time is reasonable

Comment: Minimizing the number of keys helps `INSERTs` a little.  It has no impact on `SELECTs`.

Comment: if have columns of number type instead of strings (in relations) then it speed up the select statement.